# Detecting what .txt file was used for running java

Tags: java, cmd, wmic

Im trying to figure out how to get the name of the file that was used for running my java script. I run the program with `java Test < input.txt` but when i try using wmic to get the command line of java.exe but the output i get is only `java Test`. Is there any other way of doing it?

Comment: could you please eloborate more on this

Comment: It seems as though you're piping the data in from a file. So essentially you're telling the shell to open the text file, read it and then pipe the output to your Java application. 
I'm not totally sure how Java handles this, but you might be given a file descriptor or something similar. That could then possibly be used. 

Other than that, I'd say that's 0xdeadbeef.

Comment: I want my code to "print" the name of the .txt file that was used as an input. So if i run my code with `java Test < input.txt` i want it to output `input.txt`

Comment: What i figured is is that java interprets that as if the user would manually type the inputs in but i still hope that that gets stored somewhere somehow

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use `<`? You don't need it. Just leave it out and it should work without problems.

Comment: I know its just that the program that runs the script using all the possible inputs does it that way so i dont have another option

Answer (score 1):

When you write `java Test < input.txt`, the shell you're writing that into takes 2 actions : first it reads the content of the input.txt, second it launches the `java` command with the argument "Test" and its standard input (stdin / System.in) populated with the content of input.txt.

From the launched command perspective, there never was a `< input.txt`, there's just some content on its standard input.

You might be able to do something OS-side, for instance on RHEL I can get back the file as follows :

```
$ sleep 50 < /path/to/file &
[1] 18492
$ my_process_pid=$!
$ cat /proc/$my_process_pid/cmdline
sleep50                               # no signs of the redirection
$ readlink /proc/$my_process_pid/fd/0 # but we can check what stdin links to
/path/to/file
```

It seems to me that the most straightforward way to retrieve the file name would be to force the user to pass the file's location as an argument rather than using redirections to directly consume the file's content.